# Creating Page in SharePoint 2013 error?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have SharePoint 2013 in one of my site collection I can create Sitepages but I can not create pages.

I get bellow error:

```
Sorry, something went wrong 

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1
```

I searched through the net some said that deactivate and reactivate the SharePoint publishing features I did but no success.

Comment: Are you can add list , or something like this check your event viewer and make sure that the issue is not related to database full or something like this

Comment: I can create list but I can create sitepages but I can't create page